# Youtube videos cannot be played in UIWebView (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube, uiwebview

I think I know what was my problem but I couldn't find a solution for it.
On my app, you can see that there is a YouTube video, but when you click on it, it won't play the video. Here's the line of code that may cause the issue:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(partyRock.videoURL, baseURL: nil)
```

I think that sending nil to the baseURL may cause the issue, but I'm not sure what to replace with.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `loadHTMLString`? This property sets the main page content and base URL and I don't think you want to do that.

Use this instead:

```
let requestURL = URL(string: partyRock.videoURL)
let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the quick reply!
I did try this and the problem is the URLRequest is nil, maybe the casting failed (even tho I hard-coded the string)

Comment: @B.Malka, not really sure what´s wrong with your URL. Checkout [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2TR9xoKqvZNMzhfenRsN25ob0E) sample project that I created and try it out and see if it helps you.

Comment: This sample project kinda helped me, I realized that maybe my url was not good (which is weird as hell, because its a copy-paste from youtube's embed) I used a regular link and it solved the issue. THANKS.

Comment: @RashwanL i am loading Url `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8aKKEjIO2g` but it show mw that video could not be played\. other youtube video working well. why this `url` not working ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBcIKsJBo2Y")!)
  webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Hey Rroobb, thanks for your help. This solution failed for me as well because it returned nil again, I am not sure why is that, even tho I hard coded the url (I used your url and youtube's embed url)